# Is a measure measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

This could totally be a stupid question but I'm unsure: is a measure (ie positive, countable additive on a $\sigma$ algebra, 0 for the empty set) actually a measurable function (wrt to the Borel-sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: Let's think about definitions. For a function to be measurable, the inverse image of open sets must be measurable. What is the domain of a measure? The domain is a sigma algebra. Thus, inverse images of open sets in $\mathbb R$ of the measure consists of sets of measurable sets. The Borel algebra on $\mathbb R$ doesn't say anything about these sets.

Comment: for that to work, you would need a second sigma algebra of subsets of the first sigma algebra

Comment: A measure *can* be a measurable function. See Rushabh Mehta's comment.

Comment: @Rushabh Mehta Ok, I agree, I'm not sure what this concretely means now. Inverse images of open sets in R are uncountable unions of measurable sets, hence not necessarily measurable in theory. Are you trying to say it depends on the concrete setting, but doesn't hold in generality?

Comment: I am also wondering what @RushabhMehta meant by _"The Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't say anything about these sets"_.  Neither $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$, nor the $\sigma$-algebra on $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ were introduced to the setting before the question was asked. However, this does not mean that we can't ask the question or that measure $\mu$ can't be a measurable function from $\mathcal{F}$ to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a function, a $\sigma$-algebra on the domain and a $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain, you can ask whether the function is measurable with respect to the given $\sigma$-algebras. You have only specified a $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain, so we can not answer your question.

What probably confused you is the fact that the domain of a measure is a $\sigma$-algebra on some set, so we need to consider a $\sigma$-algebra on another $\sigma$-algebra - the domain of the measure - to determine whether it is measurable.

Answer (score 4):

For a measure space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ you have that

$$
\mu^{-1}((-\infty ,c])=\{A\in \mathcal{F}:\mu(A)\leqslant c\}
$$

so you will need a $\sigma $-algebra defined in $\mathcal{F}$ to define the measurability of $\mu$. Well, you can define this $\sigma $-algebra using $\mu$, this will give an induced $\sigma $-algebra in $\mathcal{F}$, and we can note it by $\sigma (\mu)$.

Comment: Would you like to say a little bit about how exactly $\sigma(\mu)$ is defined?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Isn't $\mathcal{F}$ already a sigma-algebra? And the question was more in general, for any given $\mathcal{F}$, is a measure necessarily measurable or not... Maybe the concepts just sound similar and have no inherent relation, but I don't know of any concrete examples either.

Comment: In this answer, $F$ is already a sigma-algebra, yes. It is the domain of the measure $\mu$ that you have brought to the table. Your follow-up question "is my $\mu$ necessarily measurable?" is a not a complete notion. You need to fix a (new) sigma-algebra of subsets of $F$ to make your question meaningful; this requires a consideration of the collection $P(F)$ of all subsets of $F$. In fact you must decide which elements of $P(F)$ are "measurable" before your question is meaningful.

Comment: @311411 its the standard construction of an induced $\sigma $-algebra, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_a_function)

Comment: I guess, there is some confusion as to whether $\sigma(\mu)$ is guaranteed to exist (and to be a $\sigma$-algebra). We often start from the other end: given measurable spaces $(\Omega_1, \Sigma_1)$, $(\Omega_2, \Sigma_2)$ and a function $\mu:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ we check if $\sigma(\mu)\subseteq\Sigma_1$, and if so it is a $\sigma$-algebra or can be completed to become one. But here the situation is somewhat different: we aren't given any $\Sigma_1$. Afaic, $\{\mu^{-1}(B):B\in\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R})}\}$ is closed under complements and countable unions, and is thus the $\sigma(\mu)$.

Comment: Could you maybe add a definitive statement to your answer, like _"any measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{F}$ can be made measurable if one considers a measurable space $(\mathcal{F}, \sigma(\mu))$"_ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a seperable Hausdorff space, denote by $\mathscr{Bor}(X)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $\mathscr{Bor}(X)$. Then $x \in X \mapsto \mu (\{x\}) \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+}$ is $(\mathscr{Bor}(X), \mathscr{Bor}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+}))$-measurable.

Answer (score -1):

Given two sets $X_1,X_2$ with $\sigma$ algebras $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ the function $f:X_2 \to X_2$ is called measurable if the preimage of each measurable set in $X_2$ is measurable in $X_1$.

However a measure on $X_1$ is not a function on $X_1$. It does not take points of $X_1$ as inputs. It takes subsets as inputs. So it does not make sense to ask whether it is a measurable function or not.